# why don't spring getter methods follow javabean convention?

Tags: spring, configuration, getter, convention

I walked across many Spring tutorials explaining `@Configuration` and `@Bean` annotations, and always the `@Bean` annotation is put above a method that is returning some Spring bean but never follows the java bean getter standard. for example :

```
@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() { ... }
```

and not

```
getSessionFactory()
```

Can anyone explain why is this standard abandoned here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because by default bean name will be the same as the method name. Following the java bean getter standard you will end up with bean with name "getSessionFactory".